# How to create a column of dummies variables in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a column of time-series data looks like this

```
TimeStamp               Data
2002-01-01 00:00:00     0.00120 
2002-01-01 08:00:00     0.00070 
2002-01-01 12:00:00     0.00000 
2002-01-01 16:00:00    -0.00440 
...
2003-01-01 12:00:00     0.00220 
2003-01-01 16:00:00    -0.00440
```

In general, there are positive, negative and `0.00000` in the column. I would like to add a dummy column that all positive numbers represented by 1, negative by 0, and `0.00000` by 2. I can do this with a loop, but it doesn't seem a smart idea if I am using Pandas.

Could any one tell me the proper way of doing this in Pandas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
# initialise a column named sign
df["sign"] = [0]*df.shape[0]

# apply to all cases
df.loc[df["Data"] < 0, "sign"] = 0
df.loc[df["Data"] > 0, "sign"] = 1
df.loc[df["Data"] == 0, "sign"] = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

There's `np.sign` which gives `1,0,-1` for `+,0,-` if it works for you:

```
df['sign'] = np.sign(df['Data'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy [`select`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
df['dummy'] = np.select((df.Data<0, df.Data>0), (0,1), 2)
```

Comment: @TheHalf-BloodPrince if the data contains non-numeric data you'll get an error, as you can't compare a string to a number (this holds true for all answers here)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work.

```
df.loc[df['Data']>0,'Dummy Column'] = 1
df.loc[df['Data']<0,'Dummy Column'] = 0
df.loc[df['Data']==0,'Dummy Column'] = 2
```